# How can I record a live stream with Android Java?

Tags: java, android, tcp, vitamio, mp4parser

Right now I am displaying a live stream on a Surface using the [vitamio librairy](https://www.vitamio.org/en/).

I wish to record it in order to watch it later as the feed comes from a drone.

Right now I am periodically saving a series of bitmaps using [jcodec](http://jcodec.org/) :

```
 SequenceEncoder enc = new SequenceEncoder(new File("filename"));
// GOP size will be supported in 0.2
// enc.getEncoder().setKeyInterval(25);
for(...) {
    BufferedImage image = ... // Obtain an image to encode
    enc.encodeImage(image);
}
enc.finish();
```

My problems are :

- The h264 output from jcodec is corrupted (there is a lot of color patches on the frames)
- I can't record at a very high framerate (I'd like 30fps).

Moreover I still need to find a way to mux it.. I looked into Mp4Parser without much succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use data input stream:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (recording.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream videoFile = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
int len;
byte buffer[] = new byte[8192];

while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    videoFile.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

videoFile.close();
```

Then, you can play the video from file.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I used URLConnection.getInputStream() to get the video feed. Moreover anyone who wishes to do this must know that network operations cannot be performed in the main thread.

Comment: Hi All, I am trying recording live video from IP camera. I am able to save the images (using http protocal) and showing the live stream (using vlcj lib). But I am not able to record video, please provide your code, it will helpful for me.

Comment: we will get the inputstream from the this line  "DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (recording.getInputStream());"   And we read from that, it is onetime task correct. So how the entire video will be getting here.